# How to determine user operating system at runtime?

Tags: c

There are quite a lot of questions about it, but they all suggest doing it using compile-time macros. I know it normally doesn't make sense to check it on runtime and it's better to use compile-time macros but I can't use them here (I can't write `#ifdef _WIN32`). The C code is embedded in a higher level language. The only function I want to have is something like `isWindows()`. Is there any library that can do this on both windows and linux without recompiling it?

Comment: `int isWindows() { #ifdef _WIN32 return 1; #else return 0; }` Wouldn't this work?

Comment: There is no universal function to retrieve information about a specific host OS.  The implementation (compiler, library, etc) knows what host system it is compiling for, since it is configured with that information. The first step for a C program to get that information from the implementation is therefore testing particular macros (e.g. `#ifdef _WIN32` to detect a 32-bit windows target), and the second is using functions specific to that target. You can therefore write an `isWindows()` using such techniques. A non-windows OS won't provide one, just as Windows will not provide an `isUnix()`.

Comment: I don't think a Linux executable will run on Windows or vice versa.

Comment: @PaulOgilvie What about [Windows Subsystem for Linux](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Subsystem_for_Linux) and [Wine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wine_(software))? You can run Windows executable on Linux and Linux executable on Windows without recompiling. Compile-time checks are useless in these situations.

Answer (score 0):

If you need the information of https://sourceforge.net/p/predef/wiki/OperatingSystems/ at run-time, create functions with all those compile-time defines and query it at run-time.
I know of none, because it's trivial, and everybody does it at compile-time.

Most of the high-level languages have a library call to get the OS name and type, but usually they normalize that at compile-time also, or use their own high-level libraries.